# How to find the public ip of another computer or server on my local network?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, networking, ip

I've googled this a bit, and all I find are tips on how to find the public IP of my current machine.

I have: The target computer's local IP address and computer name; log-in credentials on the target computer.

I'm using Windows on all local machines. Ideally, I'd like a solution that I can batch (like a set of powershell commands or something).

Comment: You may get better answers asking this on the StackOverflow offshoot http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the third party server method. All computers know how to access the server, the server delivers information to each to tell the other how to communicate with each other.

If implemented well, you can use this for Hole Punching and expand the usefulness of the method.

Aside from a third party server, this info is pretty interesting (though not tested by me):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/how-do-i-know-the-ip-addresses-of-other-computers-in-my-network